# How can I remove "detail.html" from the following URLs using an .htaccess file or equivalent?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I would like to rewrite URLs like the following using an *.htaccess* file:

```
http://www.example.com/haunted_pub/detail.html
http://www.example.com/haunted_pub/west_and_south_west/detail.html
http://www.example.com/haunted_pub/west_and_south_west/wiltshire/detail.html
http://www.example.com/haunted_pub/west_and_south_west/wiltshire/bradford_on_avon/detail.html
http://www.example.com.com/haunted_pub/west_and_south_west/wiltshire/bradford_on_avon/6149/the_cross_guns/detail.html
```

So that they rewrite as:

```
http://www.example.com/haunted_pub
http://www.example.com/haunted_pub/west_and_south_west
http://www.example.com/haunted_pub/west_and_south_west/wiltshire
http://www.example.com/haunted_pub/west_and_south_west/wiltshire/bradford_on_avon
http://www.example.com/haunted_pub/west_and_south_west/wiltshire/bradford_on_avon/6149/the_cross_guns
```

Is there a rule I could use to simply truncate the final "detail.html" from whatever URL? If so then what would it be in this scenario?

**EDIT**
This is to run under IIS.

In short, if I request: http://www.example.com/haunted_pub/west_and_south_west then I want the server to render http://www.example.com/haunted_pub/west_and_south_west/detail.html but the keep name in the address bar as http://www.example.com/haunted_pub/west_and_south_west

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put this code in your htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(.+?)/detail\.html\s [NC]
RewriteRule . /%1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/detail\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1/detail.html [L]
```

---

**EDIT**

Since you're on IIS Server, you can't use htaccess file (for Apache servers only).
You'll need specific rewrite syntax in `web.config` file in your case.
But i think it exists some sort of emulators to enable htaccess on IIS servers.
Or you could also use something like [isapirewrite](http://www.isapirewrite.com/)

Comment: That was fast - let me try

Comment: http://www.example.com/haunted_pub/west_and_south_west gives a 500 error - IISPassword: The page cannot be displayed

Comment: That's another story, since `/detail.html` is removed. You're certainly on a better position to know why this url does not work

Comment: Isn't it working the other way around? I request: http://www.example.com/haunted_pub/west_and_south_west but I want the server to render http://www.example.com/haunted_pub/west_and_south_west/detail.html but in the keep name in the address bar as http://www.example.com/haunted_pub/west_and_south_west

Comment: Hmmm i see what you mean. But no, this is not automatic. I'll update my answer to take your comment into consideration (please update your question with it too)

Comment: I'll do that - I guessed it wasn't clear even though I tried to be.

Comment: That's not a problem. You can try with my edited answer

Comment: It makes sense but I think there is some permission blocking it. I'm going to contact my host.

Comment: Just to be sure... I saw `IISPassword` in your comment above. Are you on IIS server ? If so, you can't use htaccess file (for Apache servers only) but you need specific rewrite syntax in `web.config` file

Comment: Yes, I'm using IIS but it isn't a web application. It's simple html that I generated using Razor and a SQL database because they 100k pages.

Comment: Do you know how I could do this without any .Net through IIS; or do I need to use some routing framework?

Comment: Well for what i know, with IIS, you have to use IIS-rewrite syntax in `web.config` file

Comment: IIS supports PHP and cgi... Hmmm... I'll try AngularJs. It supports routing.

Comment: Yes but it does not support htaccess files by default (they are Apache specific). But i think it exists some sort of emulators to enable htaccess on IIS servers (or something like http://www.isapirewrite.com)

Comment: +1 for posting a good and and awesome support. OP: You should have tagged your question as `IIS` to avoid Apache specific answers.

Comment: @JustinIurman Put to use an .htaccess emulator or ISAPI filter in your answer and I'll give you the points.

Comment: @Carnotaurus I did, thank you, hope it helped you to solve your problem